# How to make two flatlists in one table in React-Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Can you suggest me a library that I can make that? Or a way to make it in react-native. I want to use 2 flatlists in those two options on the header, because I'm receiving data from API.

[image]

Comment: You can use one flastlist by changing the datasource only.

Comment: You can create these two tabs using [react-native-scrollable-tab-view] library and both tabs will have their own FlatLists[ horizontal ] so can be handled separately.